# Zip items in triplets from a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list A with values

```
[43.4543, 23.45343, 76.55665, 33.4345, 5]
```

I need to zip it in the following way,

```
[(43.4543,23.45343,5),(76.55665,33.4345,5)]
```

Could anyone guide me to solve this?

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes exactly. There was a typo

Comment: Could you clarify what the *general* task you're trying to accomplish is? Based on the slice it seems you're trying to split up the evenly- and oddly-indexed elements, but that doesn't match the output example. And why does the last element end up in both halves of the output?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please edit your question with expected output

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually I need to pair it and add the last element of the list to all the pairs present. For example 1st element and 2nd element as one pair and so on.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by *"pair it"*? If you had a list with *seven* items what should happen? What if there were six? Please [edit] to describe the actual task you're trying to accomplish, a single example does not illustrate the required algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` will return a list whose length is equal to length of the shortest input sequence. As the last one (`A[-1:]`) have only 1 element, you can't use zip. Try something different like that one below.

```
a = [43.4543, 23.45343, 76.55665, 33.4345, 5]
map(lambda x: x + (a[-1],), zip(a[::2], a[1::2]))
```

Comment: Alternatively, as a list comprehension: `[x + (a[-1],) for x in zip(a[:-1:2], a[1:-1:2])]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) with [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> l = [43.4543, 23.45343, 76.55665, 33.4345, 5]
>>> it = iter(l)
>>> list(zip(it, it, repeat(l[-1])))
[(43.4543, 23.45343, 5), (76.55665, 33.4345, 5)]
```

Comment: `repeat` is the more sensible choice than `cycle`. Why didn't I think of that? :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to use `zip` here. For the given data you can just assemble the desired output like this:

```
p = [a[:2] + a[-1:], a[2:]]
```

or if the list items must be tuples:

```
p = [tuple(u) for u in (a[:2] + a[-1:], a[2:])]
```

But you can do it with `zip` and `itertools.cycle`

```
from itertools import cycle

a = [43.4543, 23.45343, 76.55665, 33.4345, 5]
p = zip(a[::2], a[1::2], cycle(a[-1:]))
print(list(p))
```

**output**

```
[(43.4543, 23.45343, 5), (76.55665, 33.4345, 5)]
```

This will work on any `a` of odd length.

Instead of using `itertools.cycle`, you can use `itertools.repeat`, as in niemmi's answer.

---

Another option is to zip with an iterator of the source list:

```
from itertools import repeat

a = range(11)
head, tail = iter(a), a[-1]

p = zip(head, head, repeat(tail))
print(list(p))
```

**output**

```
[(0, 1, 10), (2, 3, 10), (4, 5, 10), (6, 7, 10), (8, 9, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`P = zip(A[::2], A[1::2], A[-1:]*2)` should give the expected output